# download helper creating zero size files

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu-10.04, download

I've got a small problem with dwhelper. Now when I'm trying to download anything from youtube DH doesn't download and creates only empty files. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [ChangeLog](http://www.downloadhelper.net/changelog.php):

> - v4.8.6
> - Fixed bug #303: Due to a change at YouTube, cannot download some high-quality videos anymore.

Also, see [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) (not sure if this is saying the problem is fixed in v4.8.6, or if there are *additional* troubles beyond that version that are still under repair):

> Recent changes at YouTube broke the download of high-quality variants on some videos. A fixed version of DownloadHelper is currently being reviewed at Mozilla and should be available very soon. By that time you can install version 4.8.6 from [this place](http://www.downloadhelper.net/install-beta.php?version=4.8.6).

Hope that helps.